# Why isn't there a closely related key to C minor that has D as tonic?

Tags: theory, chords, harmony, key, modulation

For minor keys, there are no closely related keys built on the second scale degree. Why? Is it because the chord built from the second scale degree is diminished?

[image]

Comment: Because the ii° is a diminished chord, and there are no "diminished keys" in standard usage.  There are only major and minor keys.  That's why we leave out ii°.  This is also the same for vii° in major keys.  https://www.hearandplay.com/main/there-are-no-diminished-and-augmented-keys

Answer (score 12):

Closely related keys are keys with key signatures within one accidental of each other. Find the number of accidentals in the given key signature, then find the keys that have that same number (and type) of accidentals, one less, and one more.

For instance, C minor has three flats in its key signature. The closely related keys to C minor will be:

- E♭ major (also three flats)
- B♭ major (two flats)
- G minor (two flats)
- A♭ major (four flats)
- F minor (four flats)

Another way to go about determining the closely related keys is to think through the diatonic Roman numerals of the key. In a minor key, those chords are i, ii°, III, iv, v, VI, and VII. When we translate these Roman numerals to keys, we get:

1. C minor
2. **We skip ii°** (D diminished) **because it's not a key** (at least, not in the Classical style)**.**
3. E♭ major
4. F minor
5. G minor
6. A♭ major
7. B♭ major

Answer (score 4):

Taking the minor to be a minor third from its relative major. Thus the ii° of Cm is the same as the vii° of E♭ major. That is called D°, and spelled D, F, A♭, using the same scale notes as E♭ major - C natural minor. If C melodic minor scale notes are used, that ii chord becomes Dm, spelled D, F, A.

The other question here concerns 'closely related' keys. Adding or taking away one ♯ or ♭ from the key signature. gives two options. Going to the *parallel* chord is another.

This question is now confusing to answer: of course there is a chord made on the second degree of Cm. It's D diminished, which is actually a chord, but not one that denotes (sic) a good resting place. rather it's dissonant, which is actually good, because it can lead to several other chords quite happily.